# Using python to write onto 2 different lines in a .txt file

Tags: python

I am using python to write into a .txt file. The program needs to first add something onto the first line (in this case "buffer") and then write a custom input by the user in the line under it. The program currently looks like this:

```
try:
    text = open("myconfig.txt", "x")
    text = open("myconfig.txt", "w")
    text.write(" ")
    text.close()
except FileExistsError:
    print("File already exists")
text = open("myconfig.txt", "rt")
for line in text:
    if "buffer" not in line:
        NewPassword = input("Create a new Password: ")
        text = open("myconfig.txt", "a")
        text.write("buffer \n%s" % NewPassword)
        text.close()
        break
pass
```

Problem is the program is supposed to first check the .txt file for the word "buffer" and if it exists within the .txt, it skips the writing part. And that works all good if you remove the \n to change the line its writing to. After the \n is added it no longer seems to find the "buffer" in the .txt file and keeps repeating the initial writing process.
Is there a way the program would find the word "buffer" but still write the second part into the line under it?
Thank you in advance.
Edit: To further clarify the problem, using the code written above atleast twice produces the following output onto a .txt file:

```
 buffer 
 adminbuffer 
 admin
```

where "admin" being the user inputted text. Now what should happen is it should only write it once, and if the word "buffer" already exists within the .txt file it should skip over this part. If you remove the "\n" as such:

```
text.write("buffer %s" %NewPassword)
```

it now properly skips over this step the next time you run it. Is there a way to achieve this skip but also writing the user input part onto a different line?

Comment: Do not open the same file twice, remove the first `open`. Also, format your code appropriately. As written, it is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: First, this code doesn't run because of IndentationErrors. Second, it's not clear what your problem is. Can you give us a sample input and expected vs. actual output? Or give the two versions of the code you're talking about, and the actual output in each case? Or… something like that? (And please make sure that whatever you post here actually _does_ reproduce the behavior you're asking about.)

Comment: @DyZ While that's a very weird thing to do, I don't think it's actually causing the problem here. After the second (or, rather, fourth) `open`, the old file object never gets used again, so the fact that trying to use it would be a huge mess doesn't actually matter. (Except, of course, that it makes the code confusing as hell to read—especially on top of reusing the loop variable name for another variable inside the loop, but then doing a `break` so that doesn't matter either…)

Comment: @abarnert Sorry about the indent errors at first, fixed now. I am still very new at this. Added text to further clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at trying to interpret this:

When you run the code the first time, it correctly sees that the file is just a single space, so it asks for a password and adds `buffer \n` onto that single-space line and then writes the password on the next line.

When you run the code the second time, you want it to see that `buffer` is already there and do nothing.

But that's not what you're checking. You're checking *each line* to see if `buffer` is there, not the whole file.

So, the second time you run it: For the first line, which is `" buffer \n"`,  `"buffer"` is in the line, so it does nothing. For the second line, which is the user's password, `"buffer"` probably isn't in their password. So it asks for a new password and appends it again.

If you want to check whether `"buffer"` appears anywhere in the file, there are two ways to do this.

First, check each line, and only do your writing stuff if you got to the end without finding `"buffer"` anywhere:

```
for line in text:
    if "buffer" in line:
        break
else:
    NewPassword = input("Create a new Password: ")
    text = open("myconfig.txt", "a")
    text.write("buffer \n%s" % NewPassword)
    text.close()
```

Alternatively, since this file is easily going to be small enough to read the whole thing into memory, just do that:

```
if "buffer" not in text.read():
    NewPassword = input("Create a new Password: ")
    text = open("myconfig.txt", "a")
    text.write("buffer \n%s" % NewPassword)
    text.close()
```

Either way, if I've guessed your problem correctly, this should fix it.

It's still pretty confusing code. Having multiple file objects referring to the same file at the same time is almost always a mess. Using the same variable to mean multiple different values—especially a loop iteration variable and a variable used inside the loop—is very misleading. And so on. But I think you get away with all of these things—you happen to never use any file object again after opening the next one, you `break` right after reassigning the loop variable, etc. Still, it would be better to try to clean this up so it's *obviously* right. For example:

```
try:
    with open("myconfig.txt", "x") as text:
        text.write(" ")
except FileExistsError:
    print("File already exists")

with open("myconfig.txt", "r") as text:
    hasbuffer = "buffer" in text.read()

if not hasbuffer:
    NewPassword = input("Create a new Password: ")
    with open("myconfig.txt", "a") as text:
        text.write("buffer \n%s" % NewPassword)
```